# Attempting to Display a 3x3 table with double digit numbers using char array

Tags: c++, arrays, c, visual-studio, char

I am writing this program for class and I cannot seem to figure out how to make my Char array print values bigger than 1-9 as otherwise players will have to do math to be able to calculate which slot they want. Which I feel ruins the fun of the game. However, I am newer to C++ and I cannot seem to get it to work. Any help is appreciated, this is the Array, and this is the program.

class TTTBoard {
public:

```
void PrintBoard();
char board[9] = { '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' };
char board2[9] = { "10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"};
char board3[9] =  { "19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27" };
int WinXY();
int WhosMove();
void Update();
int gameWin();
void AI();
void UserSelectASlot();
bool gameend();
```

};

My functions I have declared on in my source file, however whenever I try char * board2[9].......etc It gives me an error for many functions saying I cannot assign an int value to *char?

This is one piece of code among many others from the UserSelectASlot(); Function.

```
else if (Spot == 10 && game.board2[0] != 'O' && game.board2[0] != 'X')
    {
        game.board2[0] = 'X';
    }
```

I also tried doing char string board[9][19] however that does not work either due to errors, over 100 so it stopped counting.

My current errors for the first code above are "Too many Initializers"
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd and 3rd char arrays are actually arrays of strings (“)
so change the declaration to:

const char* array[9]

About the error you received , my guess is that you passed array[i] to a function that expects a char so replace it with array[i][0], array[i][1] those are the 2 characters in the string.

BTW,
You don’t need to work with characters but with numbers , integers and in the print function you can just map the int values to the right character.

Comment: I had that before, It gives me a different error. I read online you can use " for arrays with more symbols I believe or greater values. @Dr.Haimovitz          It states "initializing:Truncation of constant value" and "conversion from int to char requires a narrowing conversion".

Comment: I tried and it states "C2440'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [3]' to 'char *"           As well as in my main program "cannot convert from char to char* which I believe I just need to change it to char*, however everything else says "C2446 '!=': no conversion from 'int' to 'char *"

Comment: Perhaps instead of writing a large amount of code first, and only then trying to compile the whole thing, it makes more sense to write a little bit at a compile, then compile it and test it before writing more code. You should've done this, and wrote code for one array at a time. This way you would've had to deal with only a few compilation errors at a time, much easier than dealing with a huge hairball of compilation errors, all over the place.

Comment: And the compilation errors for the broken array declarations have nothing to do with the compilation errors in the actual code itself, that you mention towards the end. In fact, it's likely that they are ***caused*** by them, since the arrays are not declared properly. It might be faster for you to start from scratch, from a blank slate, and take the approach of writing only a few lines of code, at a time.

Comment: Its for a class, and I have to use my old program (regular tic tac toe) to then create a 3D tic tac toe game.

Comment: I suggest you should provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)to reproduce the issue.